# How to look up a value in a related table, and how to add a drop-down menu to an edit panel?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script which is showing me data from a MySQL table and where I am able to add/edit employees. There are 2 tables, 1 for Departments and 1 for Employees.

My script catches only data from the table Employees, but this table only shows the department ID, instead of the department name.

[image: Tables]

[image: Portal]

Now what I want is

1. to show in my "Portal" the name of the department, instead of the ID.
2. My portal now only shows a textbox, but I want to have a dropdown with the departments (see screenshot for portal look)

How can I achieve this in my current script? I have 2 files: index.php and aev.php:

```html
<?php


  #####################
  # required settings #
  #####################


session_start();
require_once("aev/aev.php");
$tabledit = new MySQLtabledit();

# database settings:
$tabledit->database = 'my_site_db';
$tabledit->host = 'localhost';
$tabledit->user = 'root';
$tabledit->pass = '****';

# table of the database
$tabledit->table = 'aevinew2_workforce_employees';

# the primary key of the table (must be AUTO_INCREMENT)
$tabledit->primary_key = 'id';

# the fields you want to see in "list view"
$tabledit->fields_in_list_view = array('id','fname','lname','position','department','phone1','phone2','geboortedatum','icon');



  #####################
  # optional settings #
  #####################


# language (en of nl)
$tabledit->language = 'nl';

# numbers of rows/records in "list view"
$tabledit->num_rows_list_view = 15;

# required fields in edit or add record
$tabledit->fields_required = array('fname','lname','position','department','phone1','geboortedatum');

# help text 
$tabledit->help_text = array(
 'id' => "Don't edit this field",
 'fname' => "Verplicht veld",
 'lname' => "Verplicht veld",
 'position' => "Verplicht veld",
 'department' => "Verplicht veld",
 'email' => "Niet verplicht",
 'phone1' => "Verplicht veld",
 'phone2' => "Alleen invullen indien van toepassing",
 'geboortedatum' => "Verplicht veld. Gebruik datum notatie YYYY-MM-DD",
 'locstate' => "Veld leeg laten",
 'featured' => "Veld leeg laten",
 'icon' => "Selecteer afbeelding (functie nog niet beschikbaar)",
 'bio' => "Veld leeg laten",
 'ordering' => "Veld leeg laten",
 'state' => "Veld leeg laten",
 'website' => "Veld leeg laten",
 'user_id' => "Veld leeg laten", 
 
);

# visible name of the fields
$tabledit->show_text = array(
  'id' => 'ID',
 'fname' => 'Voornaam',
 'lname' => 'Achternaam',
 'position' => 'Functie',
 'department' => 'Afdeling',
 'email' => 'Email',
 'phone1' => 'Telefoonnummer',
 'phone2' => 'GSM',
 'geboortedatum'=> 'Geboortedatum',
 'locstate' => 'Status geblokkeerd',
 'icon' => 'Foto',
 'bio' => 'Biografie',
 'ordering' => 'Sortering',
 'state' => 'Status',
 'website' => 'Website',
 'user_id' => 'UserID', 
);

$tabledit->width_editor = '100%';
$tabledit->width_input_fields = '500px';
$tabledit->width_text_fields = '498px';
$tabledit->height_text_fields = '200px';

# warning no .htacces ('on' or 'off')
$tabledit->no_htaccess_warning = 'off';



  ####################################
  # connect, show editor, disconnect #
  ####################################


$tabledit->database_connect();

echo "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Werknemers Aevitae</title>
 </head>
 <body>
";

$tabledit->do_it();

echo "
 </body>
 </html>"
;

$tabledit->database_disconnect();
?>
```

```html
<?php

// no direct access
if(strtolower(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) == strtolower(basename(__FILE__))) {
die('No access...');
}


class MySQLtabledit {

   /** 
* 
* Werknemersbestand Aevitae
* 
* Copyright (c) 2015 Richard Vliegen, Aevitae BV

*/

var $version = '1.0'; 

# text 
var $text;

# language
var $language = 'en';

# database settings
var $database;
var $host;
var $user;
var $pass;

# table of the database
var $table;

# the primary key of the table
var $primary_key;

# the fields you want to see in "list view"
var $fields_in_list_view;

# numbers of rows/records in "list view"
var $num_rows_list_view = 15;

# required fields in edit or add record
var $fields_required;

# help text 
var $help_text;

# visible name of the fields
var $show_text; 

var $width_editor = '100%';
var $width_input_fields = '500px';
var $width_text_fields = '498px';
var $height_text_fields = '200px';

# warning no .htacces ('on' or 'off')
var $no_htaccess_warning = 'off';



var $url_base;

var $query_joomla_component;



###########################
function database_connect() {
###########################

 if (!mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass)) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 mysql_select_db($this->database);

}



##############################
function database_disconnect() {
##############################

 mysql_close();

}




################
function do_it() {
################
 
 
 require_once("./lang/en.php");
 require_once("./lang/" . $this->language . ".php");


 # No cache
 if(!headers_sent()) {
  header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
  header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
  header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
  header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
  header("Cache-control: private");
 }

 if (!$this->url_base) $this->url_base = '.';

 # name of the script
 $break = explode('/', $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);
 $this->url_script = $break[count($break) - 1];



 if ($_GET['mte_a'] == 'edit') { 
  $this->edit_rec(); 
 }
 elseif ($_GET['mte_a'] == 'new') {
  $this->edit_rec();
 }
 elseif ($_GET['mte_a'] == 'del') {
   $this->del_rec(); 
 }
 elseif ($_POST['mte_a'] == 'save') {
  $this->save_rec();
 }
 else { 
  $this->show_list();
 }

 $this->close_and_print();

}




####################
function show_list() {
####################
 
 # message after add or edit
 $this->content_saved = $_SESSION['content_saved']; 
 $_SESSION['content_saved'] = '';
   
 # default sort (a = ascending)
 $ad = 'a';

 if ($_GET['sort'] && in_array($_GET['sort'],$this->fields_in_list_view) ) {
  if ($_GET['ad'] == 'a') $asc_des = 'ASC';
  if ($_GET['ad'] == 'd') $asc_des = 'DESC';
  $order_by = "ORDER by " . $_GET['sort'] . ' ' . $asc_des ; 
 }
 else {
  $order_by = "ORDER by $this->primary_key DESC"; 
 }


 # navigation 1/3
 $start = $_GET["start"];
 if (!$start) {$start = 0;} else {$start *=1;}

 
 // build query_string
 // query_joomla_component (joomla) 
 if ($this->query_joomla_component) $query_string = '&option=' . $this->query_joomla_component ;
 // navigation
 $query_string .= '&start=' . $start;
 // sorting
 $query_string .= '&ad=' . $_GET['ad']  . '&sort=' . $_GET['sort'] ;
 // searching
 $query_string .= '&s=' . $_GET['s']  . '&f=' . $_GET['f'] ;
 
 
 # search
 if ($_GET['s'] && $_GET['f']) {

  $in_search = addslashes(stripslashes($_GET['s']));
  $in_search_field = $_GET['f'];

  if ($in_search_field == $this->primary_key) {
   $where_search = "WHERE $in_search_field = '$in_search' ";
  }
  else {
   $where_search = "WHERE $in_search_field LIKE '%$in_search%' ";
  }
 }
 
 # select
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `$this->table` $where_search $order_by";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);

 # navigation 2/3
 $hits_total = mysql_num_rows($result); 

 $sql .= " LIMIT $start, $this->num_rows_list_view";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);


 if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
  $count = 0;
  while ($rij = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $count++;
   $this_row = '';
   
   if ($background == '#eee') {$background='#fff';} 
    else {$background='#eee';}
      
   
   foreach ($rij AS $key => $value) {
    
    $sort_image = '';
    if (in_array($key, $this->fields_in_list_view)) {
     if ($count == 1) {
      
      // show nice text of a value 
      if ($this->show_text[$key]) {$show_key = $this->show_text[$key];}
       else {$show_key = $key;}

      // sorting
      if ($_GET['sort'] == $key && $_GET['ad'] == 'a') {
       $sort_image = "<IMG SRC='$this->url_base/images/sort_a.png' WIDTH=9 HEIGHT=8 BORDER=0 ALT=''>";
       $ad = 'd';
      }
      if ($_GET['sort'] == $key && $_GET['ad'] == 'd') {
       $sort_image = "<IMG SRC='$this->url_base/images/sort_d.png' WIDTH=9 HEIGHT=8 BORDER=0 ALT=''>";
       $ad = 'a';
      }

      // remove sort  and ad and add new ones
      $query_sort = preg_replace('/&(sort|ad)=[^&]*/','', $query_string) . "&sort=$key&ad=$ad"; 

      $head .= "<td NOWRAP><a href='$this->url_script?$query_sort' class='mte_head'>$show_key</a> $sort_image</td>";
     }
     if ($key == $this->primary_key) {
      $buttons = "<td NOWRAP><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='del_confirm($value)' title='Delete {$this->show_text[$key]} $value'><IMG SRC='$this->url_base/images/del.png' WIDTH=16 HEIGHT=16 BORDER=0 ALT=''></a>&nbsp;<a href='?$query_string&mte_a=edit&id=$value' title='Edit {$this->show_text[$key]} $value'><IMG SRC='$this->url_base/images/edit.png' WIDTH=16 HEIGHT=16 BORDER=0 ALT=''></a></td>";
      $this_row .= "<td>$value</td>";
     }
     else {
      
      $this_row .= '<td>' . substr(strip_tags($value), 0, 300) . '</td>';
     }
    }
   }
   
   $rows .= "<tr style='background:$background'>$buttons $this_row</tr>";
   
  }
 }
 else {
  $head = "<td style='padding:50px'>{$this->text['Nothing_found']}...</td>";
 }


 # navigation 3/3

 # remove start= from url
 $query_nav = preg_replace('/&(start|mte_a|id)=[^&]*/','', $query_string ); 


 # this page
 $this_page = ($this->num_rows_list_view + $start)/$this->num_rows_list_view;


 # last page
 $last_page = ceil($hits_total/$this->num_rows_list_view);


 # navigatie numbers
 if ($this_page>10) {
  $vanaf = $this_page - 10;
 }
 else {$vanaf = 1;}
 if ($last_page>$this_page + 10) {
  $tot = $this_page + 10;
 }
 else {$tot = $last_page; }


 for ($f=$vanaf;$f<=$tot;$f++) {

  $nav_toon = $this->num_rows_list_view * ($f-1);

  if ($f == $this_page) {
   $navigation .= "<td class='mte_nav' style='color:#fff;background: #808080;font-weight: bold'>$f</td> "; 
  }
  else {
   $navigation .= "<td class='mte_nav' style='background: #fff'><A HREF='$this->url_script?$query_nav&start=$nav_toon'>$f</A></td>"; 
  }
 }
 if ($hits_total<$this->num_rows_list_view) { $navigation = '';}




 # Previous if
 if ($this_page > 1) {
  $last =  (($this_page - 1) * $this->num_rows_list_view ) - $this->num_rows_list_view;
  $last_page_html = "<A HREF='$this->url_script?$query_nav&start=$last' class='mte_nav_prev_next'>{$this->text['Previous']}</A>";
 }

 # Next if: 
 if ($this_page != $last_page && $hits_total>1) {
  $next =  $start + $this->num_rows_list_view;
  $next_page_html =  "<A HREF='$this->url_script?$query_nav&start=$next' class='mte_nav_prev_next'>{$this->text['Next']}</A>";
 }


 if ($navigation) {
  $nav_table = "
   <table cellspacing=5 cellpadding=0 style='border: 0px solid white'>
    <tr>
     <td style='padding-right:6px;vertical-align: middle'>$last_page_html</td>
     $navigation
     <td style='padding-left:6px;vertical-align: middle'>$next_page_html</td>
    </tr>
   </table> 
  ";

  $this->nav_top = "

   <div style='margin: -10px 0 20px 0;width: $this->width_editor'>
   <center>
    $nav_table
   </center>
   </div> 
  ";

  $this->nav_bottom = "
   <div style='margin: 20px 0 0 0;width: $this->width_editor'>
   <center>
    $nav_table
   </center>
   </div>
  ";
 }
 
 
 
 
 # Search form + Add Record button
 foreach ($this->fields_in_list_view AS $option) {
  
  if ($this->show_text[$option]) {$show_option = $this->show_text[$option];}
  else {$show_option = $option;}

  if ($option == $in_search_field) {
    $options .= "<option selected value='$option'>$show_option</option>";
   }
   else {
    $options .= "<option value='$option'>$show_option</option>";
   }
  }
 $in_search_value = htmlentities(trim(stripslashes($_GET['s'])), ENT_QUOTES);



 $seach_form = "
  <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
  <tr>
   <td nowrap>
    <form method=get action='$this->url_script' style='padding: 15px'>
     <select name='f'>$options</select> 
     <input type='text' name='s' value='$in_search_value' style='width:200px'>
     <input type='submit' value='{$this->text['Search']}' style='width:80px; border: 1px solid #000'>
  ";  
 if ($this->query_joomla_component) $seach_form .= "<input type='hidden' value='$this->query_joomla_component' name='option'>";
 $seach_form .= "</form>";
 
 if ($_GET['s'] && $_GET['f']) {  
  if ($this->query_joomla_component) $add_joomla = '?option=' . $this->query_joomla_component;
  $seach_form .= "<button onclick='window.location=\"$this->url_script$add_joomla\"' style='margin: 0 0 15px 15px; border: 1px solid #000;'>{$this->text['Clear_search']}</button>";
 }
 
 $seach_form .= "
   </td>

   <td style='padding: 15px; text-align: right; width: $this->width_editor'>
    <button onclick='window.location=\"$this->url_script?$query_string&mte_a=new\"' style='margin: 0 0 15px 15px; border: 1px solid #000;'>{$this->text['Add_Record']}</button>
   </td>
  
  </tr>
  </table>
 ";

 $this->javascript = "
  function del_confirm(id) {
   if (confirm('{$this->text['Delete']} record {$this->show_text[$this->primary_key]} ' + id + '...?')) {
    window.location='$this->url_script?$query_string&mte_a=del&id=' + id    
   }
  }
 ";
 
 
 # page content
 $this->content = "
  <div style='width: $this->width_editor;background:#454545; margin: 0'>$seach_form</div>
  <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=10 style='margin: 0; width: $this->width_editor;'>
   <tr style='background:#626262; color: #fff'><td></td>$head</tr>
   $rows
  </table>
  
  $this->nav_bottom
 ";
 
 
}




##################
function del_rec() {
##################

 $in_id = $_GET['id'];

 if (mysql_query("DELETE FROM $this->table WHERE `$this->primary_key` = '$in_id'")) {
  $this->content_deleted = "
   <div style='width: $this->width_editor'>
    <div style='padding: 10px; color:#fff; background: #FF8000; font-weight: bold'>Record {$this->show_text[$this->primary_key]} $in_id {$this->text['deleted']}</div>
   </div>
  ";
  $this->show_list();
 }
 else {
  $this->content = "
  </div>
   <div style='padding:2px 20px 20px 20px;margin: 0 0 20px 0; background: #DF0000; color: #fff;'><h3>Error</h3>" .
   mysql_error(). 
   "</div><a href='$this->url_script'>List records...</a>
  </div>";
 }

}




###################
function edit_rec() {
###################

 $in_id = $_GET['id'];

 # edit or new?
 if ($_GET['mte_a'] == 'edit') $edit=1;
 
 $count_required = 0;
 
 $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$this->table`");
 
 # get field types
 while ($rij = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  extract($rij);
  $field_type[$Field] = $Type;
 } 

 if (!$edit) {
  $rij = $field_type;
 }
 else {
  if ($edit) $where_edit = "WHERE `$this->primary_key` = $in_id";
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$this->table` $where_edit LIMIT 1 ;");
  $rij = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 }
 
 
 foreach ($rij AS $key => $value) {
  if (!$edit) $value = '';
  $field = '';
  $options = '';
  $style = '';
  $field_id = '';
  $readonly = '';
  $value_htmlentities = '';
  
  if (in_array($key, $this->fields_required)) {
   $count_required++;
   $style = "class='mte_req'";
   $field_id = "id='id_" . $count_required . "'";
  }


  $field_kind = $field_type[$key];

  # different fields
  # textarea
  if (preg_match("/text/", $field_kind)) {
   $field = "<textarea name='$key' $style $field_id>$value</textarea>";
  }
  # select/options
  elseif (preg_match("/enum\((.*)\)/", $field_kind, $matches)) {
   $all_options = substr($matches[1],1,-1);
   $options_array = explode("','",$all_options);
   foreach ($options_array AS $option) {
    if ($option == $value) {
     $options .= "<option selected>$option</option>";
    }
    else {
     $options .= "<option>$option</option>";
    }
   } 
   $field = "<select name='$key' $style $field_id>$options</select>";
  }
  # input
  elseif (!preg_match("/blob/", $field_kind)) {
   if (preg_match("/\(*(.*)\)*/", $field_kind, $matches)) {
    if ($key == $this->primary_key) {
     $style = "style='background:#ccc'";
     $readonly = 'readonly';
    }
    $value_htmlentities = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES);
    if (!$edit && $key == $this->primary_key) {
     $field = "<input type='hidden' name='$key' value=''>[auto increment]";
    } 
    else {
     $field = "<input type='text' name='$key' value='$value_htmlentities' maxlength='{$matches[1]}' $style $readonly $field_id>";
    }
   }
  }
  # blob: don't show
  elseif (preg_match("/blob/", $field_kind)) {
   $field = '[<i>binary</i>]';
  }
   
  # make table row
  if ($background == '#eee') {$background='#fff';} 
   else {$background='#eee';}
  if ($this->show_text[$key]) {$show_key = $this->show_text[$key];}
   else {$show_key = $key;}
  $rows .= "\n\n<tr style='background:$background'>\n<td><b>$show_key</b></td>\n<td>$field</td>\n<td style='width:50%'>{$this->help_text[$key]}</td>\n</tr>";
 }
 
 $this->javascript = "
  function submitform() {
   var ok = 0;
   for (f=1;f<=$count_required;f++) {
    
    var elem = document.getElementById('id_' + f);
    
    if(elem.options) {
     if (elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].text!=null && elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].text!='') {
      ok++;
     }
    }
    else {
     if (elem.value!=null && elem.value!='') {
      ok++;
     }
    }
   }
// alert($count_required + ' ' + ok);

   if (ok == $count_required) {
    return true;
   }
   else {
    alert('{$this->text['Check_the_required_fields']}...')
    return false;
   } 
  }
 ";


 $this->content = "
  

   <div style='width: $this->width_editor;background:#454545'>
   
    <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 style='border: 0px solid white'>
     <tr>
     <td>
      <button onclick='window.location=\"{$_SESSION['hist_page']}\";' style='margin: 20px 15px 25px 15px; border: 1px solid #000;'>{$this->text['Go_back']}</button></td>
     <td>
      <form method=post action='$this->url_script' onsubmit='return submitform()'>
      <input type='submit' value='{$this->text['Save']}' style='width: 80px;border: 1px solid #000; margin: 20px 0 25px 0'></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    
   </div>
  
   <div style='width: $this->width_editor'>
    <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=10 style='100%; margin: 0'>
     $rows
    </table>
   </div>
 ";
  
 if (!$edit) $this->content .= "<input type='hidden' name='mte_new_rec' value='1'>";
 if ($this->query_joomla_component) $this->content .= "<input type='hidden' name='option' value='$this->query_joomla_component'>";
 
 $this->content .= "
   <input type='hidden' name='mte_a' value='save'>
   
  </form>
 ";

 
}




###################
function save_rec() {
###################


 $in_mte_new_rec = $_POST['mte_new_rec'];
 
 $updates = '';
 
 foreach($_POST AS $key => $value) {
  if ($key == $this->primary_key) {
   $in_id = $value;
   $where = "$key = $value";
  }
  if ($key != 'mte_a' && $key != 'mte_new_rec' && $key != 'option') {
   if ($in_mte_new_rec) {
    $insert_fields .= " `$key`,";
    $insert_values .= " '" . addslashes(stripslashes($value)) . "',";
   }
   else {
    $updates .= " `$key` = '" . addslashes(stripslashes($value)) . "' ,";
   }
  }
 }
 $insert_fields = substr($insert_fields,0,-1);
 $insert_values = substr($insert_values,0,-1);
 $updates = substr($updates,0,-1);
 

 # new record:
 if ($in_mte_new_rec) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `$this->table` ($insert_fields) VALUES ($insert_values); "; 
 }
 # edit record:
 else {
  $sql = "UPDATE `$this->table` SET $updates WHERE $where LIMIT 1; "; 
 }
 

 //echo $sql; exit;
 if (mysql_query($sql)) {
  if ($in_mte_new_rec) {
   $saved_id = mysql_insert_id();
   $_GET['s'] = $saved_id;
   $_GET['f'] = $this->primary_key;
  }
  else {
   $saved_id = $in_id;
  }
  if ($this->show_text[$this->primary_key]) {$show_primary_key = $this->show_text[$this->primary_key];}
   else {$show_primary_key = $this->primary_key;}

  $_SESSION['content_saved'] = "
   <div style='width: $this->width_editor'>
    <div style='padding: 10px; color:#fff; background: #67B915; font-weight: bold'>Record $show_primary_key $saved_id {$this->text['saved']}</div>
   </div>
   ";
  if ($in_mte_new_rec) {
   echo "<script>window.location='?start=0&f=&sort=" . $this->primary_key . "&ad=d";
   if ($this->query_joomla_component) {
    echo '&option=' . $this->query_joomla_component ;
   }
   echo "'</script>";
  }
  else {
   echo "<script>window.location='" . $_SESSION['hist_page'] . "'</script>";
  }
 }
 else {
  $this->content = "
   <div style='width: $this->width_editor'>
    <div style='padding:2px 20px 20px 20px;margin: 0 0 20px 0; background: #DF0000; color: #fff;'><h3>Error</h3>" .
    mysql_error() . 
    "</div><a href='{$_SESSION['hist_page']}'>{$this->text['Go_back']}...</a>
   </div>";
 }
}




##########################
function close_and_print() {
##########################


 # debug and warning no htaccess
 if ($this->debug) $this->debug .= '<br />';
 if (!file_exists('./.htaccess') && $this->no_htaccess_warning == 'on') $this->debug .= "{$this->text['Protect_this_directory_with']} .htaccess";

 if ($this->debug) 
 $this->debug_html = "
  <div style='width: $this->width_editor'>
   <div class='mte_mess' style='background: #DD0000'>$this->debug</div>
  </div>";


 # save page location
 $session_hist_page = $this->url_script . '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
 if ($this->query_joomla_component && !preg_match("/option=$this->query_joomla_component/",$session_hist_page)) {
  $session_hist_page .= '&option=' . $this->query_joomla_component;
 }
 
 // no page history on the edit page because after refresh the Go Back is useless 
 if (!$_GET['mte_a']) {
  $_SESSION['hist_page'] = $session_hist_page;
 }


 
 if ($this->query_joomla_component) $add_joomla = '?option=' . $this->query_joomla_component;
 
 echo "
 <script language='javascript'>
  $this->javascript
 </script>

 <link href='$this->url_base/css/mte.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

 <style type='text/css'>
  .mte_content input {
   width: $this->width_input_fields;
  }
  .mte_content textarea {
   width: $this->width_text_fields;
   height: $this->height_text_fields;
  }
 </style> 

 <div class='mte_content'>
  <div class='mte_head_1'><a href='$this->url_script$add_joomla' style='text-decoration: none;color: #797979'>Aevitae Werknemers</a> <span style='color: #ddd'>$this->version</span></div>
  <div class='mte_logo'></div>
  $this->nav_top
  $this->debug_html
  $this->content_saved
  $this->content_deleted
  $this->content
 </div>
 
 "; 
 
}  
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this?

Comment: A number of your class methods have serious SQL injection vulnerabilities. Aside from that, you're asking how to make quite substantial changes, so we can probably only offer broad descriptions on how to do it.

Comment: Tips on asking questions, on any source of help on the web: (1) show what you have tried, (2) use specific titles relating to your problem, (3) ask about one problem at a time.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the lookup issue, I take it your class does not support this natively? You'll need to add the feature. I'd do something like this:

```
/**
 * Converts a FK column to a lookup column
 *
 * @param $columnName The name of the column in the current table
 * @param $foreignTable The name of the foreign table
 * @param $foreignKey The primary key in the foreign table
 * @param $foreignTextColumn The column to use as a lookup
 */
public function declareLookupColumn($columnName, $foreignTable, $foreignKey, $foreignTextColumn)
{
    // @todo Store these values in your class, so you can examine
    // them when the table is rendered
}
```

You'll also need to modify your table rendering code. For each column, see if it has been declared with this method, and if so, issue a `SELECT` to fetch the foreign table value.